# How can I pass relative paths to CMake using the command line?

Tags: cmake

I have a `.cmd` file which executes the CMake executable that looks like this,

```
cmake ... -DCMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE=C:\random\my_cmake_project\project_hook.cmake
```

This works fine, however, my `.cmd` file is located inside of `C:\random\my_cmake_project\` and I am trying to create a generalized solution and avoid hard coded paths. However, I cannot seem to make this work using relative paths.

When I change the path to,

```
cmake ... -DCMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE=".\project_hook.cmake"
```

It says it cannot find `project_hook.cmake`. The `.cmd` is in the same directory as `project_hook.cmake`. Does CMake not accept relative paths?

Comment: Relative paths are relative to the current working directory, which is the directory your `cmd` file is _called from_, not the directory where the file is.

Comment: @tkausl I can verify that it does not work, given the current calling location.